# destructuring default values in function params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I'm trying to destructure values directly in params fonction and affect default values with a general object (for each subProperties destructured) :

Example

```js
const initialTest = {
  name: 'myName',
  surname: 'mySurname',
  age: 100,
};

const MyComponent = ({
   test: { name, surname, age } = initialTest,
}) => { ... }

<MyComponent test={{ name: 'myNameFromProps' }} />
```

My final desir is to have 3 const `name`, `surname` and `age`, with values from `props` (params of the function) if they are defined, and values from `initialTest` if not.

With this code, if `test` is not defined in props of component, it will use initialTest, but if test is defined with only `name` props like example above, I will get :

```
name = 'myNameFromProps'
surname undefined
age undefined
```

and I want :

```
name = 'myNameFromProps'
surname = 'mySurname'
age = 100
```

For sur I can do it with :

```
const MyComponent = ({
   test: { name = initialTest.name, surname = initialTest.surname, age = initialTest.age },
}) => { ... }
```

But that's absolutly not funny...

I tried with parentheses `test: ({ name, surname, age } = initialTest),` but does not works and eslint is saying I'm a stupid dev... and he is right xD

If you have any suggestions / idea / solution, I would be happy to read it. Thx to all !

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're actually using `initialTest` elsewhere, you can remove it and list the default values inside the destructuring of `test`:

```
const MyComponent = ({
   test: { name: 'myName', surname: 'mySurname', age: 100 } = {},
}) => { ... }
```

Make sure to have the `= {}` at the end there, in case nothing exists in the `test` property.

Comment: Yea i know, but I will use it everywhere for default payload props like { data, isLoading, errors } on every components =D, thx !

Comment: If you use it multiple places, and you don't want to be repetitive, make a function for it. `const myComponent = (arg) => { const { name, surname, age } = getDefaults(arg);`. Technically, you could also do it in the parameter list, but that'd be pretty confusing to readers of the code

Comment: Yea I can do that, but it's not cool =D I know how to solve my problem, but I'm to know if it's possible de do it the way I tried, but I don't think so. I'm reading every articles speaking about destructuring default value and I find nothing... I'm always searching the best way do it without tricks. JS can do so much things that tones of us ignore =D Thx for your help anyway, appreciate a lot